# Google OAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch still occurring despite trying several solutions

Tags: google-oauth

I am currently trying to connect to Google OAuth with JS on server-side and am getting this error despite trying everything I could find on the web.

```js
$('#sign-in-button').click(function () {
    auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(signInCallback);
});
function signInCallback(result) {
    console.log(result)
    console.log(typeof result)
    if (result['code']) {
        $('#sign-in-button').prop('disabled', true);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (successResult) {
                //todo next flow stage
                console.log('Ready to proceed to next stage!')
            },
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(result)
        })
    } else {
        // todo handle error
        console.log('An error occurred within the OAuth stage.')
    }
}
```

The code above is what I am using on the client.  The below code is the Express route for /auth.

```js
app.post('/auth', function (req, res) {
    if (req.header('X-Requested-With')) {
        let oAuth2Client = getOAuthClient(); // this method uses return new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl) where redirect url = 'http://localhost:8080/link'.
        let code = req.body['code'];
        if (code) {
            oAuth2Client.getToken(code, function (error, tokens) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.stack);
                    console.log('Whoops, an error occurred!')
                    res.send('An error occurred during the OAuth backend stage.')
                } else {
                    console.log('No error.')
                    console.log(tokens)

                    google.options({auth: oAuth2Client})
                }
            })
        } else {
            //todo fail no code
            console.log('Code failure.')
        }
    } else {
        //todo return fail CSRF
        console.log('CSRF failure.')
    }
})
```

On cloud console, you can see my efforts of trying every possible URI under the sun!
[image]

Most strangely, in the Gaxios error, the URI is correct in the request body!

But I still get `redirect_uri_mismatch`

What can I try to fix this other than what I have listed below?

- Add all the extra URI variants to cloud console
- Use oAuth2Client.getAuthUrl() instead of my client side code
- Different redirect URI (with & without slash etc.)